# What's the best method for Dual boot for my system?

Tags: windows-10, boot, kali-linux

I want to explore Kali by installing it. Also might like to remove it later.
I literally have no idea about dual boot thing and while researching online, I found many who are having issues while removing Linux distro and going back to previous state.
Using Kali with USB drive or by partition of hard drive...Which will be a better way so that I don't face complexities when removing Kali?
(I don't want to use it with windows subsystem for linux though)

Here are my PC config : 
Windows 10 1903, 4gb RAM, Core i3 7th Gen.

Comment: Honestly, if you're not even sure how to install Kali, it will do you no good at all to have it. See [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method to avoid any issues at all is to just simply use a USB drive and avoid touching your existing OS drive. You can change your boot order in your computers BIOS to default to booting to that drive instead of your main OS for a while to test it out and can change the BIOS boot settings any time. When you're done messing about then you can decide what kind of permanent setup you want to have.